# how to get image width with server-side vbscript? Asp classic

Tags: asp-classic, vbscript

I have been trying for days to find a way to get the image width of .png files which reside on our server.  I am trying to read the first 24 bytes of the file and parse out the width from bytes 17-20.  I have found several routines on the web but have not been successful.  Strangely enough, it seems I am getting the height from bytes 21-24 decoded from hex to decimal just fine.  I have verified the file contents using a hex viewer and the file is good.  Here is the main portion of the routine:

```
Function ReadPNG(fichero)
Dim fso, ts, s, HW, nbytes
    HW = Array("0", "0")
    Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set ts = fso.OpenTextFile(Server.MapPath("\forums\attachments/" & fichero), 1)
    s = Right(ts.Read(24), 8)
    HW(0) = HexToDec(HexAt(s,3) & HexAt(s,4))
    HW(1) = HexToDec(HexAt(s,7) & HexAt(s,8))
    ts.Close
    ReadPNG = HW
End Function

Function HexAt(s, n)
    HexAt = Hex(AscAt(s, n))
End Function

Function HexToDec(ByVal HexVal)

Dim i, num, part
num = 0
For I = 1 to Len(HexVal)
    part = Mid(StrReverse(UCase(HexVal)), I, 1)
    If IsNumeric(part) Then
        num = num + (CInt(part) * 16 ^ (I - 1) )
    Else
        num = num + ( (Asc(part) - 55) * 16^(I - 1) )
    End If
Next

HexToDec = num

End Function
```

As an example, my file has hex "00 00 01 80" in the width bytes (decimal 384)
                       and hex "00 00 01 32" in the heigth bytes (decimal 306)

I am getting the heigth 306 but thee width is returning "0011" (decimal 17).

I am totally stummped!  I do not have to use this routine either.

Thanks,
Jim

Comment: In your title, do you mean *server-side* VBScript?

Comment: You clearly *do* mean server-side, I've fixed the title for you.

Answer (score 5):

Here is a post I saw awhile ago, looks like it could possibly simplify things a bit. I have not tested, so let me know your results.

```
<%
dim iWidth, iheight
sub ImgDimension(img)
dim myImg, fs
Set fs= CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
if not fs.fileExists(img) then exit sub
set myImg = loadpicture(img)
iWidth = round(myImg.width / 26.4583)
iheight = round(myImg.height / 26.4583)
set myImg = nothing
end sub

ImgDimension(Server.MapPath("server image file"))
%>
```

See here for post: http://www.haneng.com/asp-forum/ASP---Get-Image-Size_12971.html

UPDATE: Seeing that this method will not work in 64bit. Here is a link to another alternative method: https://web.archive.org/web/20210608180909/http://www.4guysfromrolla.com/webtech/050300-1.shtml

Comment: LoadPicture docs: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/66bd1sx9(VS.85).aspx  Doesn't expressly mention PNG, but it may well support them.

Comment: If it doesn't work with png's, I can use another file type.  I shall test this and advise.  Thanks guys!

Comment: I have seen some posts that show this with PNG's so I am hopeful.

Comment: Oh boy! Loadpicture doesn't work on 64bit platforms!  Out of luck there.

Comment: Durilai,  Yes actually I have tried that logic. It was pointing to the wrong position in the file which I corrected, but that routine seems to return the problem I have described.

Comment: The idea here is to limit the width displayed in the browser.  Anything larger than 820 pixels should display at 820.  Unfortunately the CSS Max-width does not work in IE, works fine in Firefox.

Comment: Ahhh, I see the problem...  I need to convert the first part of the file to an ascii string from the binary file.  There is code from 4Guys to do this. I will try that.

Comment: @Jim Then run your vbscript using the 32 bit version of wscript (on that 64 bit machine). Example:
c:\windows\syswow64\wscript c:\path\to\your.vbs

Comment: I have been using this, but loadpicture produces 800a004b Path/File_access_error in my Windows Logs. Any way to prevent this?

Answer (score 2):

I use this simple function to return width, height and file size (eg. 640x480 - 200KBytes):

```
   Function ImgDim(img)
    Dim objFSO, objGF, objLP, imgWdt, imgHgt, imgSiz
    img = Server.MapPath("/pictures/"& img) 'path to picture
    Set objFSO= CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    If objFSO.fileExists(img) Then
     Set objGF = objFSO.GetFile(img)
      imgSiz = objGF.Size
     Set objGF = Nothing
     Set objLP = loadpicture(img)
      imgWdt = round(objLP.width / 26.4583)
      imgHgt = round(objLP.height / 26.4583)
     Set objLP = Nothing
     Set fs = Nothing
     ImgDim = imgWdt &"x"& imgHgt &" - "& imgSiz/1024 &"KBytes"
    End If
   End Function
```

works beautifully, hope it helps.

Comment: I have been using this, but loadpicture produces 800a004b Path/File_access_error in my Windows Logs.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a generic set of functions I found ages ago for getting information on an image. I'll put the way I've been using it at the end.

```
':::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::'
':::                                                             :::'
':::  This routine will attempt to identify any filespec passed  :::'
':::  as a graphic file (regardless of the extension). This will :::'
':::  work with BMP, GIF, JPG and PNG files.                     :::'
':::                                                             :::'
':::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::'
':::          Based on ideas presented by David Crowell          :::'
':::                   (credit where due)                        :::'
':::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::'
':::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::'
':::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::'
'::: blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah :::'
'::: blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah :::'
'::: blah blah     Copyright *c* MM,  Mike Shaffer     blah blah :::'
'::: blah blah      ALL RIGHTS RESERVED WORLDWIDE      blah blah :::'
'::: blah blah  Permission is granted to use this code blah blah :::'
'::: blah blah   in your projects, as long as this     blah blah :::'
'::: blah blah      copyright notice is included       blah blah :::'
'::: blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah :::'
'::: blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah :::'
':::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::'

':::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::'
':::                                                             :::'
':::  This function gets a specified number of bytes from any    :::'
':::  file, starting at the offset (base 1)                      :::'
':::                                                             :::'
':::  Passed:                                                    :::'
':::       flnm        => Filespec of file to read               :::'
':::       offset      => Offset at which to start reading       :::'
':::       bytes       => How many bytes to read                 :::'
':::                                                             :::'
':::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::'
function GetBytes(flnm, offset, bytes)

 Dim objFSO
 Dim objFTemp
 Dim objTextStream
 Dim lngSize

 on error resume next

 Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

 ' First, we get the filesize'
 Set objFTemp = objFSO.GetFile(flnm)
 lngSize = objFTemp.Size
 set objFTemp = nothing

 fsoForReading = 1
 Set objTextStream = objFSO.OpenTextFile(flnm, fsoForReading)

 if offset > 0 then
    strBuff = objTextStream.Read(offset - 1)
 end if

 if bytes = -1 then        ' Get All!'

    GetBytes = objTextStream.Read(lngSize)  'ReadAll'

 else

    GetBytes = objTextStream.Read(bytes)

 end if

 objTextStream.Close
 set objTextStream = nothing
 set objFSO = nothing

end function


':::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::'
':::                                                             :::'
':::  Functions to convert two bytes to a numeric value (long)   :::'
':::  (both little-endian and big-endian)                        :::'
':::                                                             :::'
':::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::'
function lngConvert(strTemp)
 lngConvert = clng(asc(left(strTemp, 1)) + ((asc(right(strTemp, 1)) * 256)))
end function

function lngConvert2(strTemp)
 lngConvert2 = clng(asc(right(strTemp, 1)) + ((asc(left(strTemp, 1)) * 256)))
end function


':::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::'
':::                                                             :::'
':::  This function does most of the real work. It will attempt  :::'
':::  to read any file, regardless of the extension, and will    :::'
':::  identify if it is a graphical image.                       :::'
':::                                                             :::'
':::  Passed:                                                    :::'
':::       flnm        => Filespec of file to read               :::'
':::       width       => width of image                         :::'
':::       height      => height of image                        :::'
':::       depth       => color depth (in number of colors)      :::'
':::       strImageType=> type of image (e.g. GIF, BMP, etc.)    :::'
':::                                                             :::'
':::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::'
function gfxSpex(flnm, width, height, depth, strImageType)

 dim strPNG 
 dim strGIF
 dim strBMP
 dim strType
 strType = ""
 strImageType = "(unknown)"

 gfxSpex = False

 strPNG = chr(137) & chr(80) & chr(78)
 strGIF = "GIF"
 strBMP = chr(66) & chr(77)

 strType = GetBytes(flnm, 0, 3)

 if strType = strGIF then                ' is GIF'

    strImageType = "GIF"
    Width = lngConvert(GetBytes(flnm, 7, 2))
    Height = lngConvert(GetBytes(flnm, 9, 2))
    Depth = 2 ^ ((asc(GetBytes(flnm, 11, 1)) and 7) + 1)
    gfxSpex = True

 elseif left(strType, 2) = strBMP then        ' is BMP'

    strImageType = "BMP"
    Width = lngConvert(GetBytes(flnm, 19, 2))
    Height = lngConvert(GetBytes(flnm, 23, 2))
    Depth = 2 ^ (asc(GetBytes(flnm, 29, 1)))
    gfxSpex = True

 elseif strType = strPNG then            ' Is PNG'

    strImageType = "PNG"
    Width = lngConvert2(GetBytes(flnm, 19, 2))
    Height = lngConvert2(GetBytes(flnm, 23, 2))
    Depth = getBytes(flnm, 25, 2)

    select case asc(right(Depth,1))
       case 0
          Depth = 2 ^ (asc(left(Depth, 1)))
          gfxSpex = True
       case 2
          Depth = 2 ^ (asc(left(Depth, 1)) * 3)
          gfxSpex = True
       case 3
          Depth = 2 ^ (asc(left(Depth, 1)))  '8'
          gfxSpex = True
       case 4
          Depth = 2 ^ (asc(left(Depth, 1)) * 2)
          gfxSpex = True
       case 6
          Depth = 2 ^ (asc(left(Depth, 1)) * 4)
          gfxSpex = True
       case else
          Depth = -1
    end select


 else

    strBuff = GetBytes(flnm, 0, -1)        ' Get all bytes from file'
    lngSize = len(strBuff)
    flgFound = 0

    strTarget = chr(255) & chr(216) & chr(255)
    flgFound = instr(strBuff, strTarget)

    if flgFound = 0 then
       exit function
    end if

    strImageType = "JPG"
    lngPos = flgFound + 2
    ExitLoop = false

    do while ExitLoop = False and lngPos < lngSize

       do while asc(mid(strBuff, lngPos, 1)) = 255 and lngPos < lngSize
          lngPos = lngPos + 1
       loop

       if asc(mid(strBuff, lngPos, 1)) < 192 or asc(mid(strBuff, lngPos, 1)) > 195 then
          lngMarkerSize = lngConvert2(mid(strBuff, lngPos + 1, 2))
          lngPos = lngPos + lngMarkerSize  + 1
       else
          ExitLoop = True
       end if

   loop

   if ExitLoop = False then

      Width = -1
      Height = -1
      Depth = -1

   else

      Height = lngConvert2(mid(strBuff, lngPos + 4, 2))
      Width = lngConvert2(mid(strBuff, lngPos + 6, 2))
      Depth = 2 ^ (asc(mid(strBuff, lngPos + 8, 1)) * 8)
      gfxSpex = True

   end if

 end if

end function
```

I've been using it to generate a randomized XML file for an image library. The script only gets run when I finish uploading a new image to the library.

Here's the usage: (or at least how I used it)

```
'collect the image information into an array'
Dim blnGfxSpex, width, height, colors, strType
intCount = 0
For Each objFile In objFS.GetFolder(".\images").Files
    If LCase(Right(objFile.Name, 4)) = ".jpg" and intCount <= intNumOfFiles Then
        blnGfxSpex = gfxSpex((".\images\" & objFile.Name), width, height, colors, strType)

        arrImages(intCount) = "<image>" & vbNewLine & _
                                "<filename>" & objFile.Name & "</filename>" & vbNewLine & _
                                "<caption></caption>" & vbNewLine & _
                                "<width>" & width & "</width>" & vbNewLine & _
                                "<height>" & height & "</height>" & vbNewLine & _
                                "</image>" & vbNewLine
        intCount = intCount + 1
    End If
Next
```

As you can see, I'm initializing the variables for width, height, etc. and the function sets them as appropriate. I know it's not kosher to use global variables like that, but it works.

Performance isn't as bad as you would think. In this particular case I am filtering the image library to just JPGs, but that is due to a limitation in the image library the XML is for, not due to a limitation in the functions.

Comment: This doesn't work on any of my PNG files. They are valid, photoshop and preview (macos) both recognise them, as does the browser. I'm getting the width as a large number but the height is correct, e.g. `02386C87651E40209D6802DAD046F3FE.png => -15430, 300` The source article is here: http://www.4guysfromrolla.com/webtech/050300-1.shtml.

Answer (score 0):

This code also work for .png images! Unfortunately not for .webp images. I am still in search for something that will also support .webp images.

found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57493341/6500909)

```
set oIMG = CreateObject("WIA.ImageFile")
oIMG.loadFile(path)
iHeight = oIMG.Height
iWidth = oIMG.Width
set oIMG = nothing
```