# Need to read width/height from graphics file with VBScript/ASP classic

Tags: vbscript, graphics, asp-classic

I need to read a graphics file and get the width/height in VBScript (ASP). I found a package called `gfxSpex` that seems to be what a lot of people use but the GIFs get the width right but not the height. PNGs don't work at all as the routine is looking for the type in 0-3 and that's %PN in the .png files.

```
Function gfxSpex(flnm, width, height, depth, strImageType)
    Dim strPNG
    Dim strGIF
    Dim strBMP
    Dim strType
    strType = ""
    strImageType = "(unknown)"

    gfxSpex = False

    strPNG = Chr(137) & Chr(80) & Chr(78)
    strGIf = "GIF"
    strBMP = Chr(66) & Chr(77)

    strType = GetBytes(flnm, 0, 3)

    If strType = strGIf Then                ' is GIF
        strImageType = "GIF"
        Width = lngConvert(GetBytes(flnm, 7, 2))
        Height = lngConvert(GetBytes(flnm, 9, 2))
        Depth = 2 ^ ((Asc(GetBytes(flnm, 11, 1)) And 7) + 1)
        gfxSpex = True
    ElseIf Left(strType, 2) = strBMP Then       ' is BMP
        strImageType = "BMP"
        Width = lngConvert(GetBytes(flnm, 19, 2))
        Height = lngConvert(GetBytes(flnm, 23, 2))
        Depth = 2 ^ (Asc(GetBytes(flnm, 29, 1)))
        gfxSpex = True
    ElseIf strType = strPNG Then            ' Is PNG
        strImageType = "PNG"
        Width = lngConvert2(GetBytes(flnm, 19, 2))
        Height = lngConvert2(GetBytes(flnm, 23, 2))
        Depth = getBytes(flnm, 25, 2)

        Select Case Asc(right(Depth,1))
            Case 0
                Depth = 2 ^ (Asc(left(Depth, 1)))
                gfxSpex = True
            Case 2
                Depth = 2 ^ (Asc(left(Depth, 1)) * 3)
                gfxSpex = True
            Case 3
                Depth = 2 ^ (Asc(left(Depth, 1)))  '8
                gfxSpex = True
            Case 4
                Depth = 2 ^ (Asc(left(Depth, 1)) * 2)
                gfxSpex = True
            Case 6
                Depth = 2 ^ (Asc(left(Depth, 1)) * 4)
                gfxSpex = True
            Case Else
                Depth = -1
        End Select
    Else
        strBuff = GetBytes(flnm, 0, -1)     ' Get all bytes from file
        lngSize = Len(strBuff)
        flgFound = 0

        strTarget = Chr(255) & Chr(216) & Chr(255)
        flgFound = InStr(strBuff, strTarget)

        If flgFound = 0 Then
            Exit Function
        End If

        strImageType = "JPG"
        lngPos = flgFound + 2
        ExitLoop = False

        Do While ExitLoop = False And lngPos < lngSize
            Do While Asc(Mid(strBuff, lngPos, 1)) = 255 And lngPos < lngSize
                lngPos = lngPos + 1
            Loop

            If Asc(Mid(strBuff, lngPos, 1)) < 192 Or Asc(Mid(strBuff, lngPos, 1)) > 195 Then
                lngMarkerSize = lngConvert2(Mid(strBuff, lngPos + 1, 2))
                lngPos = lngPos + lngMarkerSize  + 1
            Else
                ExitLoop = True
            End If
        Loop

        If ExitLoop = False Then
            Width = -1
            Height = -1
            Depth = -1
        Else
            Height = lngConvert2(Mid(strBuff, lngPos + 4, 2))
            Width = lngConvert2(Mid(strBuff, lngPos + 6, 2))
            Depth = 2 ^ (Asc(Mid(strBuff, lngPos + 8, 1)) * 8)
            gfxSpex = True
        End If
    End If
End Function

Function GetBytes(flnm, offset, bytes)
    Dim objFSO
    Dim objFTemp
    Dim objTextStream
    Dim lngSize

    On Error Resume Next

    Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

    ' First, we get the filesize
    Set objFTemp = objFSO.GetFile(flnm)
    lngSize = objFTemp.Size
    Set objFTemp = Nothing

    fsoForReading = 1
    Set objTextStream = objFSO.OpenTextFile(flnm, fsoForReading)

    If offset > 0 Then
        strBuff = objTextStream.Read(offset - 1)
    End If

    If bytes = -1 Then      ' Get All!
        GetBytes = objTextStream.Read(lngSize)  'ReadAll
    Else
        GetBytes = objTextStream.Read(bytes)
    End If

    objTextStream.Close
    Set objTextStream = Nothing
    Set objFSO = Nothing
End Function

Function lngConvert(strTemp)
    lngConvert = CLng(Asc(Left(strTemp, 1)) + ((Asc(Right(strTemp, 1)) * 256)))
End Function


Function lngConvert2(strTemp)
    lngConvert2 = CLng(Asc(Right(strTemp, 1)) + ((Asc(Left(strTemp, 1)) * 256)))
End Function
```

Is anyone using this `gfxSpex` function and have they modified it?  Is there a better way to get the width and height?

Comment: Yep, that will work!  Never knew about WIAimage!

Comment: Looks like whatever comment you replied to is now deleted for some reason. If you found a solution, please post it as answer.

Comment: Anyway, I used gfxSpex for years as part of my file upload (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15874740/pure-asp-upload-with-image-detection)) and it worked just fine, for all image types as far as I remember. That was years ago though.

Comment: Do you still have the gfsSpex code?  Any different than what I posted?

Comment: I have the code, but no classic ASP server. And too lazy to install one. :)

Answer (score 4):

Yes, I'm not sure why the comment was deleted!  Basically, it gave me a link to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/image/wia-image-processing-filter.  It's a lot more than I needed but good to know it's there.  I just used:

```
set oIMG = CreateObject("WIA.ImageFile")
oIMG.loadFile(path)
iHeight = oIMG.Height
iWidth = oIMG.Width
set oIMG = nothing
```

It worked for gif, jpg, and png's.  I didn't even need to register it.

Comment: You may accept your own answer to your question. It'll help people know that you found the solution.

Comment: is did not get this to work  on .webp images

Answer (score 0):

If you have root access to your server I have a COM DLL that uses [ExifTool](https://www.sno.phy.queensu.ca/~phil/exiftool/) to analyse file information and meta data for any file type and return the results as a JSON string.

Here's an example implementation:

```
Function file_information(ByVal full_path)

    Dim ExifTool : Set ExifTool = Server.CreateObject("ClassicASP.ExifTool")

        ' If the file isn't found it returns an error string: "Error: the file... couldn't be found"

        file_information = ExifTool.FileInfo(full_path)

    Set ExifTool = nothing

End Function 

Response.Write file_information(Server.MapPath("image.png"))
```

Output:

```
[  
   {  
      "SourceFile":"C:/inetpub/wwwroot/exiftool/image.png",
      "ExifToolVersion":11.57,
      "FileName":"image.png",
      "Directory":"C:/inetpub/wwwroot/exiftool",
      "FileSize":"4.5 MB",
      "FileModifyDate":"2019:08:14 15:34:18+01:00",
      "FileAccessDate":"2019:08:14 15:34:06+01:00",
      "FileCreateDate":"2019:08:14 15:34:17+01:00",
      "FilePermissions":"rw-rw-rw-",
      "FileType":"PNG",
      "FileTypeExtension":"png",
      "MIMEType":"image/png",
      "ImageWidth":1600,
      "ImageHeight":1354,
      "BitDepth":8,
      "ColorType":"RGB with Alpha",
      "Compression":"Deflate/Inflate",
      "Filter":"Adaptive",
      "Interlace":"Noninterlaced",
      "ImageSize":"1600x1354",
      "Megapixels":2.2
   }
]
```

The files and installation instructions are available at: https://github.com/as08/ClassicASP.ExifTool

Comment: Is it working on .webp files?

Comment: @MeSo2 It works on any file type.